# Create column based on presence of string pattern and ifelse

Tags: regex, r, if-statement

I would like to fill in a new column with one of two values if a pattern is matched.

Here is my data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(loc_01 = c("apis", "indu", "isro", "miss", "non_apis", 
"non_indu", "non_isro", "non_miss", "non_piro", "non_sacn", "non_slbe", 
"non_voya", "piro", "sacn", "slbe", "voya"), loc01_land = c(165730500, 
62101800, 540687600, 161140500, 1694590200, 1459707300, 1025051400, 
1419866100, 2037064500, 2204629200, 1918840500, 886299300, 264726000, 
321003900, 241292700, 530532000)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), .Names = c("loc_01", "loc01_land"))
```

And looks like this...

```
     loc_01 loc01_land
1      apis  165730500
2      indu   62101800
3      isro  540687600
4      miss  161140500
5  non_apis 1694590200
6  non_indu 1459707300
7  non_isro 1025051400
8  non_miss 1419866100
9  non_piro 2037064500
10 non_sacn 2204629200
11 non_slbe 1918840500
12 non_voya  886299300
13     piro  264726000
14     sacn  321003900
15     slbe  241292700
16     voya  530532000
```

I would like to add a column to `df`, called 'loc_01'. If loc_01 contains *non*, then return 'outside', if it does not contain *non*, then return 'inside'. This is my ifelse statement, but I'm missing something because it only returns the `false` value.

```
df$loc01 <- ifelse(df$loc_01 == "non", 'outside', 'inside')
```

And the resulting df...

```
     loc_01 loc01_land  loc01
1      apis  165730500 inside
2      indu   62101800 inside
3      isro  540687600 inside
4      miss  161140500 inside
5  non_apis 1694590200 inside
6  non_indu 1459707300 inside
7  non_isro 1025051400 inside
8  non_miss 1419866100 inside
9  non_piro 2037064500 inside
10 non_sacn 2204629200 inside
11 non_slbe 1918840500 inside
12 non_voya  886299300 inside
13     piro  264726000 inside
14     sacn  321003900 inside
15     slbe  241292700 inside
16     voya  530532000 inside
```

Thanks
-al

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To check if a string contains a certain substring, you can't use `==` because it performs an *exact matching* (i.e. returns true only if the string is exactly "non").
You could use for example `grepl` function (belonging to [grep family of functions](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html)) that performs a *pattern matching*:

```
df$loc01 <- ifelse(grepl("non",df$loc_01),'outside','inside')
```

Result :

```
> df
     loc_01 loc01_land   loc01
1      apis  165730500  inside
2      indu   62101800  inside
3      isro  540687600  inside
4      miss  161140500  inside
5  non_apis 1694590200 outside
6  non_indu 1459707300 outside
7  non_isro 1025051400 outside
8  non_miss 1419866100 outside
9  non_piro 2037064500 outside
10 non_sacn 2204629200 outside
11 non_slbe 1918840500 outside
12 non_voya  886299300 outside
13     piro  264726000  inside
14     sacn  321003900  inside
15     slbe  241292700  inside
16     voya  530532000  inside
```

Comment: @digEmAll how would you extend this solution to a list of values to match on? Instead of just "non", what if I wanted to match on "du" or "bis" or "lb", so that if df$loc01 contains any of these values, the loc01 column would be "inside", and if none of the 3 matched, the loc01 column would be "outside"?

Comment: @user3614783: you could use a more complex regular-expression, e.g. : `grepl("du|bis|lb",df$loc_01)`

Comment: Thanks @digEmAll. I tried applying this to my specific problem and got a warning message "input string 317 is invalid in this locale." My code, based on your example is: clean$SeriesReader<-ifelse(grepl("n/a|na|none|do not|not really|not committed|not a fan|NOne|not fan",clean$FavoriteSciFiFantasySeries),"No","Yes")

Comment: You probably have some characters in FavoriteSciFiFantasySeries which is not supported by your locale... you could try to follow the suggestion in this thread : [link](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Strings-from-different-locale-td3023176.html)

Answer (score 7):

You only need *one line* of code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)


df %>% 
  mutate(loc01 = if_else(str_starts(loc_01, "non_"), "outside", "inside"))
```

For using more complex regex-pattern you can use `str_detect` instead `str_starts`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(loc01 = if_else(str_detect(loc_01, "^(non_)"), "outside", "inside"))
```

Output:

```
   loc_01   loc01_land loc01  
   <chr>         <dbl> <chr>  
 1 apis      165730500 inside 
 2 indu       62101800 inside 
 3 isro      540687600 inside 
 4 miss      161140500 inside 
 5 non_apis 1694590200 outside
 6 non_indu 1459707300 outside
 7 non_isro 1025051400 outside
 8 non_miss 1419866100 outside
 9 non_piro 2037064500 outside
```