# Merging words in a wordcloud made in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning, word-cloud, corpus

I have created a word cloud with the following frequency of terms:

```
interesting interesting   21
economics     economics   12
learning       learning    9
learn             learn    6
taxes             taxes    6
debating       debating    6
everything   everything    6
know               know    6
tax                 tax    3
meaning         meaning    3
```

I want to add the 6 counts for "learn" into the overall count for "learning" so that the frequency becomes 15, and I only have "learning" in my word cloud. I also want to do the same for "taxes" and "tax".

This is the code I used to generate the wordcloud.

```
dataset <- read.csv("~/filepath.csv")
> corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(dataset$comment))
> clean_corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
> wordcloud(clean_corpus, scale=c(5,0.5), max.words=100, random.order = FALSE, rot.per=0.35, colors=my_palette)
```

I have tried using the SnowballC package, but this was the outcome:

```
> library(SnowballC)
> clean_set <- tm_map(clean_corpus, stemDocument)
> dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(clean_set)
> m <- as.matrix(dtm)
> v <- sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE)
> d <- data.frame(word = names(v), freq=v)
> head(d, 10)
```

This gives me the output below (economics has become econom, debating has become debat, everything, everyth) which is obviously unideal. I only have an issue with learn/learning and tax/taxes, so would it be possible to manually merge just those two sets of words?

```
interest     interest   21
learn           learn   18
econom         econom   12
tax               tax    9
debat           debat    6
everyth       everyth    6
know             know    6
mean             mean    3
understand understand    3
group           group    3
```

I have also tried `clean_corpus_2 <- tm_map(clean_corpus, content_transformer(gsub), pattern = "taxes", replacement = "tax", fixed = TRUE)` which changed nothing in the output.

Comment: Yes - you can check if a string (call it `x`) is in a set by using the pattern `x %in% c("learn", "learning")`.  Combined with an `if/else` pattern you can say "if X is one of these, return this, else if it's one of these, return this, otherwise just return the x".  Apply that function to your word list.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I tried the following code which returned 0 rows (`clean_corpus <- ifelse(clean_corpus$comment %in% c("learn", "learning"))`). I haven't used pipe operators before, so still on the learning curve for this - can you advise how to correct this code?

Comment: I've also realised I have "learning", "learned" and "learn" in my table, which I would like to condense down to just "learn". Is there a way I can combine this ifelse function with e.g. grepl() to say "if the string contains the sequential letters "learn" then just return "learn"? (read about grepl() here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372082/create-column-based-on-presence-of-string-pattern-and-ifelse)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the tidyverse packages, particularly `dplyr` as that's why I'm comfortable with, but I'm sure this is doable with base R or any number of other approaches.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

First I mock up some data as I don't have yours to test on:

```
testdata <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~comment,
  1, "learn",
  2, "learning",
  3, "learned",
  4, "tax",
  5, "taxes",
  6, "panoply"
)
```

Next is the explicitly listing the options approach:

```
testdata1 <- testdata %>% mutate(
  newcol = case_when(
    comment %in% c("learn", "learning", "learned") ~ "learn",
    comment %in% c("tax", "taxes") ~ "tax",
    TRUE ~ as.character(comment)
  )
)
```

In this code, `%>%` is a pipe, `mutate()` adds a new column based on what follows. `newcol` is the name of the new column, and its contents is decided by the `case_when()` construct, which tests each option in turn until it finds something returning "TRUE" - that's why the last option (the default "don't change" approach) is listed as `TRUE ~` .

After that, the pattern-matching (grepl) approach:

```
testdata2 <- testdata %>% mutate(
  newcol = case_when(
    grepl(comment, pattern = "learn") ~ "learn",
    grepl(comment, pattern = "tax") ~ "tax",
    TRUE ~ as.character(comment)
  )
)
```

Yielding:

```
> testdata1
# A tibble: 6 × 3
     ID comment  newcol 
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>  
1     1 learn    learn  
2     2 learning learn  
3     3 learned  learn  
4     4 tax      tax    
5     5 taxes    tax    
6     6 panoply  panoply
> testdata2
# A tibble: 6 × 3
     ID comment  newcol 
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>  
1     1 learn    learn  
2     2 learning learn  
3     3 learned  learn  
4     4 tax      tax    
5     5 taxes    tax    
6     6 panoply  panoply
```